# Passing in lambda with recursion

Tags: python

I'm trying to pass in lambda.

```py
def summation(n, term):
    if (n == 0):
        return
    else:
        return summation(n - 1, term) + term

print(summation(5, lambda x: x + 1))
```

To my understanding, `lambda x : x + 1` will become `term` and `term` will evaluate to `n + 1` in the function, but this doesn't work. Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Should you have return 0 after the if? I think you will have none as return value.

Answer (score 5):

A `lambda` is a function. So `term` is a function. If you want `term` to evaluate to `n + 1` you must call it with `n`: `term(n)`.

You also have another issue, you have an empty `return`, which will automatically become `return None`. Did you mean `return 0`?

Comment: @gymguy42 If my answer (or anyone else's) has answered your question, consider accepting their answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: says I can in like 5 minutes

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors with your function:

```py
def summation(n, term):
    if (n == 0):
        # You were just returning here, since you use
        # the results of this function as a value, you
        # always need to return a value
        return 0
    else:
        # "term" here is a function, so you need to call it
        # with a value
        return summation(n - 1, term) + term(n)

print(summation(5, lambda x: x + 1))
```